# Changing button value of a jQuery mobile with a setTimeout function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am facing a very challenging problem due to my little knowledge in jQuery mobile. I have researched many solutions and implemented them but does not seem to work

1. I have a button called `click me`
2. When a user clicks on the button, the button becomes `disabled` and the text `clickme` changes to `please wait...`
3. After 2 seconds the button become activated (no longer `disabled`) and the text changes from `please wait...` back to `click me`.
4. I have gotten it to work to some extent. but i am finding it difficult to grab the right html code line in order to change `click me` to `please wait...`.
5. i am trying to use the example in this jsfiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/ncSbz/1/ but integrate it within my `setTimeout` code.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated. My code is below:

> html content by jquery mobile

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    clickme
    <input class="submit button-primary btn large send" id="wp-submit" name="up_submit" tabindex="250" type="button" value="clickme">
</div>
```

> jquery mobile code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clicked = false;

    $('#wp-submit').bind('click', function() {
        if(clicked == false) {
            // store reference to the button clicked
            // this allows us to access it within the 
            // setTimeout callback below.
            var $btn = $(this);

            $btn.button('disable');
            $btn.prev('div').find('div.ui-input-btn').text('Please wait...'); // sets the text
            $btn.val('Please wait...'); // sets the text on the button itself
            clicked = true;

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $btn.button('enable'); 
                $btn.prev('a').find('span.ui-btn-text').text('click me');
                $btn.val('click me');
                clicked = false;
            }, 2000); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () {...
```

Use the jQM page events like pagecreate:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageid", function () {...
```

Other than that, changing the button text is as easy as updating the value of the input and then calling button("refresh") on the jQM button widget:

```
$btn.val('Please wait...').button('refresh');
```

Putting it all together:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {

    var clicked = false;
    $('#wp-submit').on('click', function() {
        if(clicked == false) {
            var $btn = $(this);
            $btn.button('disable').val('Please wait...').button('refresh');
            clicked = true;

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $btn.button('enable').val('click me').button('refresh');
                clicked = false;
            }, 2000); 
        }
    });

});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xznsz1s5/)**

Thie also works in earlier versions of jQM: **[DEMO 1.3](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xznsz1s5/1/)**