# button style is messed up after changing the text through jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

So I have a button whose text I want to update so that one of the character is of say red color. The way I am achieving is by setting html to the button.

```
<div data-role="page" id="homepage">
   <div data-role="content">
    <a id='mybutton' href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="check">My Button</a>
   </div>    
</div>
```

​and here is how I update it through jQuery

```
.redtext{color:red;font-size:medium;text-shadow: aqua;}​

$("#mybutton").html("My Button(<span class='redtext'>0</span>)");​
```

The zero do come in red color but the button shape is now distorted and style removed it seems. Please see it a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/tqeF9/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.ui-btn-text` to your selector.

E.g. `$("#mybutton .ui-btn-text").html("My Button(<span class='redtext'>0</span>)");​`

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009535/503550) for the reason.