# jQueryMobile - looping each button to change text of nested tag on click with ajax

Tags: jquery-mobile, text, each

I have a page that will make an external call on a button click, and then update the button to reflect success.  The ajax calls work properly, however I am having difficulty trying to manipulate the text of the button when there are many on the page.

It is easy enough to match using  `$(".sabPauRes.ui-btn-text").text("Updated");` when it's the only item on the page, but I am not sure how to point to it using $(this) when I am using the each function.  I read a bit about 'closest', but it doesn't seem to accomplish what I want (or I'm just doing it wrong).

Code sample below!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sabPauRes').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: this.href,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "text",
                success: onSuccess
            })
        })

        $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
            $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
        })

        function onSuccess(data)
        {
            // validate the result of the ajax call, update text, change button methods as needed
            if (data == "Success") {
                // PROBLEM -- how do I use $this to match a class that is nested within it?
                $(this).closest(".ui-btn-text").text("Updated");
            } else {
                alert("Failed: " + data);
            }
            $("#resultLog").html("Result: " + data);

        }
    })
})
```

html

```html
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>This is an item</h3>
        <p>
                <a href="/api/?resume=fhdh54" class="sabPauRes" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-request="resume">Resume Download</a>


            <div id="resultLog"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer within [Change button text jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009524/change-button-text-jquery-mobile)

If you assign $(this) to a variable, then you can reference it in the .text() function as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sabPauRes').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $(this).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: onSuccess
        })
    })

    $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
        $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
    })

    function onSuccess(data)
    {
        // validate the result of the ajax call, update text, change button methods as needed
        if (data == "Success") {
            alert(data);
            $(".ui-btn-text",$this).text("Updated");
        } else {
            alert("Failed: " + data);
        }
        $("#resultLog").html("Result: " + data);

    }
})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Please stop using jquery ready handler when working with jQuery Mobile. Give your page an `id` and use `pageinit()` event instead.

> **[pageinit = DOM ready](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)**
>
> One of the first things people learn in jQuery is to use the
>   $(document).ready() function for executing DOM-specific code as soon
>   as the DOM is ready (which often occurs long before the onload event).
>   However, in jQuery Mobile site and apps, pages are requested and
>   injected into the same DOM as the user navigates, so the DOM ready
>   event is not as useful, as it only executes for the first page. To
>   execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created in jQuery
>   Mobile, you can bind to the pageinit event.

You can save a ref to the clicked button and use it in `success` and `error` handlers like this:

```js
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){
    $(document).on("click", "a.sabPauRes", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        //Save a ref to the clicked button
        $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data){
                // validate the result of the ajax call, update text, change button methods as needed
                if (data == "Success") {
                    $this.find(".ui-btn-text").text("Updated");
                } else {
                    $this.find(".ui-btn-text").text("Failed");
                }
                $("#resultLog").html("Result: " + data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $this.find(".ui-btn-text").text("Error");
                $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + $this.attr("href") + "<br />HTTP Code: " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText);
            }
        })

    });
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/mkEMk/)

Comment: @user2012899 Did it help? Do you need more help with the question?